# Reading line by line using fread and fseek

Tags: c, string, file, fread, fseek

im trying to read a .txt file, line by line, where each line is 19 characters long, this is my code (I want to only use fseek and fread to understand pointers rightly):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(file == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        return 0;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char L[20];
    while(1){
        if(feof(file)){
            break;
        }
        fseek(file, i*20, SEEK_SET);
        fread(L,19,sizeof(char),file);
        printf("%s\n", L);
        i++;
        }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;   
 }
```

What I think should happen with this is that I move the pointer to the file to the start of each line in a loop, then move one line and so. The source .txt file is:

```
123456789:123456789
perro:guau         
gato:miau          
                   
vaca:muuu          
                   
lobo:auuu
```

while the output I get from my program is:

```
123456789:123456789�V
perro:guau         �V
gato:miau          �V
                   �V
vaca:muuu          �V
                   �V
lobo:auuu          �V
                   �V
                   �V
```

I tried changing the 20s and 19s since I dont know if im including the end of string character in the right way, but got even worse results, any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Where do you make sure `L` is 0-terminated before treating it like a string?

Comment: `char L[20] = {0};` may help.

Comment: I think you mean L[19]. The indexing is zero-based.

Comment: Check `fread()` return value, not [`feof()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).

Comment: If you are reading a line of 19-chars -- what are you doing with the `'\n'` at the end of each line? Or is that included in your total? According to `"123456789:123456789"` it isn't... (pointers and `fread()` are not related concepts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- OP's code has *undefined behavior*, (UB) as  `"%s"` expects a *string*. Yet `L[]` lacks a *null character*. To print a character array, use `"%.*s"`
- Check `fread()` return value, not [`feof()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).
- Use return value of `fread()` to know how much was read.
- Review argument order for `fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);`

Sample:

```
size_t sz = sizeof L / sizeof L[0];
size_t n;
while((n = fread(L,sizeof L[0], sz, file)) > 0) {
  printf("<%.*s>\n", (int) n, L);
  i++;
  fseek(file, i*20, SEEK_SET);
}
```

---

`fread()` is not the best tool to read a *line*.  Research `fgets()` instead.

"each line is 19 characters long," --> C defines a *line* as "each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character."  From a C-point-of-view, your *lines* include a new-line and so are 20 characters total.